# How to use canDeactivate with routing not inside ts file?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I have implemented the guard and added it to the relevant routing like  path: `"quotes",
   children: [  { path: "", component: QuotesComponent},

      { path: "create", component: CreateQuoteComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]},

      { path: ":id", component: CreateQuoteComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]}`
     ]

I also added a condition inside the relevant component like:

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    let agreeToLeave = false;
    if (this.changesSaved === false) {
      let message = 'You have not saved your current work and will lose changes. Are you want to proceed?';
      let data = { 'message': message, 'toShowCancel': true, 'buttonYesCaption': 'Yes', 'buttonNoCaption': 'No' };
      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YesNoComponent, {
        width: '600px',
        height: '250px',
        data: data
      });

      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        if (result) {
          agreeToLeave = true;
          return true;
        }
      });
      return agreeToLeave;
    }else{
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I see the modal window asking each time when I click on any of the buttons but if I click "yes" it doesn't go to the relevant page.

Again in my case all the routings are in html files like:

```
<mat-list-item [routerLink]="['/events']" routerLinkActive="activated">
    <button mat-icon-button>
      <mat-icon>comment</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

Many thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAiLB.png)

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want to do, and what you curreny have/tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `afterClosed()` is an async operation. In fact it is an Promise. You return `false`with the default value of `agreeToLeave` before your modal is closed. Instead of returning boolean simply return the Promise itself.

```
canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if (this.changesSaved) {
      return true;
    }

    const message = 'You have not saved your current work and will lose changes. Are you want to proceed?';
    const data = { 'message': message, 'toShowCancel': true, 'buttonYesCaption': 'Yes', 'buttonNoCaption': 'No' };
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(YesNoComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      height: '250px',
      data: data
    });

    return dialogRef.afterClosed(); // if necessary map to boolean with map operator
  }
```

Edit: added some improvements to your code

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that it should be promise but I have no idea how to do it in this case :(